# Hide menu from homepage

Tags: menus, navigation

I am using the [WP- Spirit 01](http://www.template-joomspirit.com/theme-wordpress/theme-01/)  theme and would like to know how can I hide the navigation menu ONLY from the website homepage. I don't have my website live yet. 
The css code bellow works to hide the menu everywhere not the homepage.

```
.drop-down ul{
    display:none;
}
```

Will be very thankful and happy if someone helps me as soon as possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to short circuit the menu by conditionally `return`ing an empty string by adding this code to your theme `functions.php` :

```
add_filter( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', 'wpse_210095');
function wpse_210095($menu) {
  if (is_home()) {
   $menu = '';
  }
  return $menu;
}
```

[You can see in the Core where this logic executes](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L246):

```
260         $nav_menu = apply_filters( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', null, $args );
261 
262         if ( null !== $nav_menu ) {
263                 if ( $args->echo ) {
264                         echo $nav_menu;
265                         return;
266                 }
267 
268                 return $nav_menu;
269         }
```

Comment: What to do in order to have the menu showing on phone view? Thank you.

Comment: I'd have to look through the theme to see how "mobile" is being managed and I don't have time for that.

Comment: It's worth pointing out something about `is_home()`. ` * If a static page is set for the front page of the site, this function will return true only
 * on the page you set as the "Posts page".`